# Variable change on $_GET and fix otherwise

Tags: php, session

#### So I want to use `$user_country` in this way:

- when I have no `country=` in the URL I want `$user_country` to be the country from the database;
- when I have `country=United States` in the URL I want `$user_country` to change from it's original country from the db to United States and **stick** to it's value until the next URL value change of `country`;

  ```
   session_start();
   $emailc=$_SESSION["email"];
   $req1=mysql_query("SELECT country FROM users WHERE email='$emailc'");
   $countryz= mysql_fetch_assoc($req1);

  //Get country from URL:
    $country = isset($_GET['country']) ? $_GET['country'] : null;

  //Check the URL to see if we change $user_country

  if(isset($country)){
     $_SESSION['country']=$_GET['country'];
   }
    else{
    $_SESSION['country']=$countryz['country'];
  }

  //Assign value to `$user_country`
    $user_country=$_SESSION['country'];
  ```

#### My problem:

**www.example.com?country=United States**
In this case `$user_country` =United States.
After I refresh `$user_country`  comes back to it's value from the database.
I want `$user_country` to be equal to United States even after refresh, until the value of the **country** in URL changes again;
Until **www.example.com?country=Canada**, I want `$user_country`=United States, so I can use the value `$user_country` of it in my future conditions

Comment: Are you using again the  `session_start()` method in the page you are redirecting to?

Comment: No, and no I am not trying to redirect, I am catching the value of `country` from the URL if it exists so I can use if like I explained in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when the user navigates away you are setting the value from DB into the session. So updating your code(adding a elseif) should work

```
if(isset($country)){
   $_SESSION['country']=$_GET['country'];
} elseif (empty($_SESSION['country'])) {
  $_SESSION['country']=$countryz['country'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When your user log in or start to bowse your site you have to give a basic value to the country in the `$_SESSION`.

`if (empty($_SESSION['country'])) {
  $_SESSION['country'] = initializeCountry();
}`

After the initial set you have to change the value only if the $_GET parameter is set, so your code looks like this:

`if(isset($country)){
   $_SESSION['country']=$_GET['country'];
 }`

Without the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem occurs in this line

```
$country = isset($_GET['country']) ? $_GET['country'] : null;
```

Your code override country to null if you refresh page 
 Thats why you have to check if $_GET not exist then get country from session

```
   if ( isset($_GET['country']) ) {
    $country = $_GET['country'];    
  } else {
    $country = isset($_SESSION['country']) ? $_SESSION['country'] : null;
  }
```

Your full code:

```
session_start();
 $emailc=$_SESSION["email"];
 $req1=mysql_query("SELECT country FROM users WHERE email='$emailc'");
 $countryz= mysql_fetch_assoc($req1);

 //Get country from URL:
 // Add this code
  if ( isset($_GET['country']) ) {
    $country = $_GET['country'];    
  } else {
    $country = isset($_SESSION['country']) ? $_SESSION['country'] : null;
  }
  //$country = isset($_GET['country']) ? $_GET['country'] : null;

//Check the URL to see if we change $user_country

if(isset($country)){
   $_SESSION['country']=$_GET['country'];
 }
  else{
  $_SESSION['country']=$countryz['country'];
}

//Assign value to `$user_country`
  $user_country=$_SESSION['country'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your code as below:-

```
session_start();
$emailc=$_SESSION["email"];
$req1=mysql_query("SELECT country FROM users WHERE email='$emailc'");
$countryz= mysql_fetch_assoc($req1);

//Get country from URL:
$country = (isset($_GET['country'])  && !empty($_GET['country'])) ? $_GET['country'] : $countryz['country'];

//Set session variable

$_SESSION['country']=$country; 

//Assign value to `$user_country`
$user_country=$_SESSION['country'];
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few important bugs.
You should:
1) Database should select when the else statemenet is using.
2) I think that you want to use if statement in 
`$country = isset($_GET['country']) ? $_GET['country'] : null;` 
but I think you should use 
`$country = (isset($_GET['country'])) ? $_GET['country'] : null;`
Instead null, set it to value. You don't need to make second if.